# concatenating and printing uniq records with multi line files

Tags: shell

I have a file with this structure:

File1

```
>seq1
AGGGTGTG
AGGGTGTG
AGTG
>seq2
AAAGGTGT
AAGTG
>seq3
AAGGTGT
GTGTGT
```

File2

```
>seq1
AGGGTGTG
AGGGTGTG
AGTGGGT
>seq2
AAAGGTGT
AA
>seq5
AAGGTGT
GTGTGT
```

I need to concatenate the two files, remove duplicate lines based on the identifier ">" and get the union, output should be like this:

```
>seq1
AGGGTGTG
AGGGTGTG
AGTG
>seq2
AAAGGTGT
AAGTG
>seq3
AAGGTGT
GTGTGT
>seq5
AAGGTGT
GTGTGT
```

Having only the sequence IDs, that is line starting with ">", I managed to do this but the following commands in shell:

```
cat file1 file1 | sort -n | uniq > output
```

But now this doesn't work because sort will end up putting all the sequences one after the other. I was wondering how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is output really correct? Why is `AA` not showing under `seq2`?

Comment: Because although sequence IDs, that is the lines starting with ">" are exactly the same, the contents may differ in the beginning or at the end of the sequence with more or less number of letters. I wrote the output like this intentionally to show the contents may differ.

Comment: Maybe, one can remove the end of the line character, so, then, we have a more unified structure, that is one line with ID and one line with the sequence.